# What is more reliable - apt-mark or APT-pin (/etc/apt/preferences.d/pin) for version locking?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, pinning

Usually on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I lock package versions with APT-pin functionality.

For example if I want to pin `meld` to version *1.5.3-1ubuntu1* I create the following pin-file:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-meld
Package: meld
Pin: version 1.5.3-1ubuntu1
Pin-Priority: 1337
EOF
```

This file applies settings system-wide: `apt`, `apt-get`, `aptitude` and GUI tools such as `synaptic` and `muon` respects it.

I know other mechanism - `apt-mark`. Let's assume.
My starting point - I have manually installed *meld_1.5.3-1ubuntu1*, its pin is removed.

```
$ apt-mark showhold
$ apt-cache policy meld 
meld:
  Installed: 1.5.3-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 3.14.2-1
  Version table:
     3.14.2-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
 *** 1.5.3-1ubuntu1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Then I hold installed version.

```
$ sudo apt-mark hold meld
meld set on hold.

$ dpkg -l | grep meld
hi  meld                                          1.5.3-1ubuntu1                               all          graphical tool to diff and merge files
```

APT-mark shows it is on hold. But `apt-cache policy meld` have no changes

```
$ apt-cache policy meld 
meld:
  Installed: 1.5.3-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 3.14.2-1
  Version table:
     3.14.2-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
 *** 1.5.3-1ubuntu1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

`apt-get upgrade` reports that `meld` is *kept back*:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  meld
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

But if I launch `aptitude` in interactive mode I have `meld` in *Upgradable Packages*:

```
Actions  Undo  Package  Resolver  Search  Options  Views  Help
C-T: Menu  ?: Help  q: Quit  u: Update  g: Preview/Download/Install/Remove Pkgs
aptitude 0.7.4
--\ Upgradable Packages (1)
  --\ gnome - The GNOME Desktop Environment (1)
    --\ universe - Unsupported Free Software. (1)                                                                                                    
ih    meld    1.5.3-1ubuntu1 3.14.2-1
```

and if I accidentally select *Actions -> Cancel pending actions* the hold will be removed.

As far I can understand `synaptic` ignores `apt-mark` markings, its *Lock Version* functionality works differently.
`meld` is listed here as *Installed (upgradeable)*. *Mark all upgrades* button does not auto-select it, but package may be accidentally upgraded by *Mark for Upgrade*.

Muon works in same manner with packages, held by `apt-mark`. But what is interesting its option *Lock at Current Version* writes pin-file to `/etc/apt/preferences.d/meld`.

Am I understand correctly that APT-pin is more reliable than `apt-mark`?

Comment: I'm not sure *reliable* is the right term. Both should work.  If one does not work, that's a bug. Be consistent in your use - don't mix the methods. I think perhaps you have uncovered a few papercut-bugs in apt.

Comment: I do not mix methods. I see here, on askubuntu some answers, which rely on apt-mark. I use pinning always.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, pinning is more reliable, than `apt-mark`.

What I have discovered:

- last 12-14 years Synaptic uses its own pinning file (/var/lib/synaptic/preferences) - see [bug 42178 on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/synaptic/+bug/42178).
  For system-wide one may want to set symlink between `/etc` and Synaptic

  ```
  sudo ln -s /etc/apt/preferences.d/synaptic /var/lib/synaptic/preferences
  ```

  so it is workaround, locking versions in Synaptic is not recommended method (this file does not read by `apt-get` and `aptitude`).
- Muon uses system-wide pin files per-application in `/etc/apt/preferences.d`.
- `aptitude` has two bugs:

  1. on 14.04 LTS it does not respect `apt-mark` completely (see [my bug 1747189 at launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1747189)).
  2. on 16.04 LTS holds, which were set by `apt-mark` are lost after clicking on *Actions -> Cancel pending actions* (see [my bug 1747191 at launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1747191)).

  but in 18.04 LTS `aptitude` do not have such bugs, it is great.

**So my conclusion is the following: `apt-mark` is usable only if you install/remove/upgrade software only with `apt-get`, otherwise you should use pinning (i.e. `/etc/apt/preferences.d/`), it is more reliable and straightforward.**

---

Note: to prevent package installation pin priority should [be negative](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences):

> P < 0 :
>         prevents the version from being installed

for example `Pin-Priority: -10`.

Comment: Do you know if `apt-mark` is more universally respected in 18.04? In a comment on your ticket, it was noted that the bug apparently does not affect 18.04, but not sure if there might be other quirks around 18.04...

Comment: I do not know about 18.04 LTS, I'm currently running a lot of 16.04 LTS systems. And I see that `apt-mark` is not reliable here. So I'll recommend and continue to use pinning here.

Comment: Just curious if there are any updates to this before I jump off the cliff with `python-eyed3` in 16.04 and clobber it with `python-eyed3` from 18.04. Also when you say `apt-mark` is ok for `apt-get` does that apply to `apt`?

Comment: Just pinned some stuff in 20.04 LTS, pinning is still reliable here.