# APT pinning in preferences.d behaviour change from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, apt

I'm attempting to do the equivalent of holding a package via `/etc/apt/preferences.d/something.pref` in 16.04, and the behaviour seems to have changed from 14.04.

Given some package `foo` that has an installed version like 2.16.0.2~trusty, in 14.04, the following stanza will prevent `apt-get upgrade` from upgrading `foo`:

```
Package: foo
Pin: version 1
Pin-Priority: 501
```

You'll note that `version 1` does not in fact match anything close the the actual package version.

The same stanza, in 16.04, does not appear to have any effect. Is there a way to do this? I'm aware of `apt-mark hold foo`, but for various internal reasons that's not as good a solution if using a pin is possible.

The only difference I observe is that when running `apt-cache policy foo`, on 14.04 I see output that starts like this:

```
foo:
  Installed: 2.16.0.2-2~trusty
  Candidate: 2.16.0.2-2~trusty
  Package pin: (not found)
```

But on 16.04 the `Package pin: (not found)` is not present.

Running a bare `apt-cache policy` also includes lines like the following on 14.04

```
Pinned packages:
     foo -> (not found)
```

while on 16.04 the `Pinned packages:` section is entirely empty.

Comment: See my [Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/1002703/66509) - it uses syntax that working for me on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.