# How to PIN virtualbox-ext-pack (6.1.6-1) [multiverse] to not be upgraded

Tags: apt

I want [the virtualbox-ext-package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/virtualbox-ext-pack) package not to be updated because it always ends up freezing `apt`.

I tried to make a PIN in `nano /etc/apt/preferences.d/virtualbox-ext-pack-pin-99` but I don't know **how to fill in the PIN release data correctly**

```
    Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-????
Pin-Priority: 99
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is more reliable - apt-mark or APT-pin (/etc/apt/preferences.d/pin) for version locking?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002703/what-is-more-reliable-apt-mark-or-apt-pin-etc-apt-preferences-d-pin-for-ver)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @N0rbert - i know the PIN command already, but I dont know how to set the Pin: release data correctly for the virtualbox-ext-pack.

Comment: You have to consult with output of `apt-cache policy virtualbox-ext-pack` and then use its data for correct pin syntax.

Comment: @N0rbert could you explain how to do that in an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You already have all the elements from https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/virtualbox-ext-pack page.

To create pin-file you can use single command below:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-vbox-ext
Package: virtualbox-ext-pack
Pin: version 6.1.6-1
Pin-Priority: 1337
EOF
```

It will lock `virtualbox-ext-pack` package at *6.1.6-1* version forever.