# PPA: Install old version

Tags: apt, ppa, versions, apt-cache

I am trying to install package `qelectrotech` on ubuntu 18.04. 
After installing I got (old) version `0.5-2`. So I added a PPA (`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scorpio/qelectrotech-dev`) source to get the newer version. But they don't work automatically. Now I need to manually force "downgrade" and look for the version to get a new version of `0.90`. 
After checking, I realised that my ubuntu system added some version info before the actual version! 
I see old (original `0.5-2` ) the old version `1:0.5-2` and the version in PPA (new `0.90.r7446`) as `0.90.r7446`.

As `0.90.r7664` seems older than `1:0.5-2`, I always get the old version installed instead of the new. So how to get rid of that `1:`, as this is not the part of the original version?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bad moment here is that you do not want to **read** [QElectroTech-dev
PPA description](https://launchpad.net/%7Escorpio/+archive/ubuntu/qelectrotech-dev) on its page.
The developer clearly states:

> QElectroTech Ubuntu Repository for 0.9 devel version.
>
> Ubuntu pinning
> The following entry assigns a high priority to all
> versions of the QElectroTech package beginning with 0.80. :
> This way,
> your system will download the higher package version from the ppa and
> not those from the official Ubuntu repositories.
>
> Create manually the file 40qelectrotech-devel in
> /etc/apt/preferences.d/ and add these 3 lines:
>
> Package: qelectrotech*
> Pin: version 0.90.*
> Pin-Priority: 1001
>
> https://qelectrotech.org/wiki_new/start?id=en/doc/install_ubuntu
>
> apt-get install qelectrotech qelectrotech-data qelectrotech-examples
> qet-tb-generator

So you need to really create such file with relevant version by using command below:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/40qelectrotech-devel
Package: qelectrotech*
Pin: version 0.90.*
Pin-Priority: 1001
EOF
```

and then install these 0.90 versioned packages by:

```
sudo apt-get install qelectrotech qelectrotech-data qelectrotech-examples
```

Comment: I missed the ppa description as well :)

Comment: "do not want to read" - > Just passed to the end of screen where ppa link is. It works for now.

Comment: Thanks for help and and special thanks to Algnis who profread my bad english.

Comment: Got response from PPA owner, pinning command is now added to the description. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

First, create a new folder, and enter it.

```
mkdir qelectrotech && cd qelectrotech
```

Then, download the relevant packages from the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Escorpio/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages).

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~scorpio/+archive/ubuntu/qelectrotech-dev/+files/qelectrotech_0.90.r7446-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/~scorpio/+archive/ubuntu/qelectrotech-dev/+files/qelectrotech-data_0.90.r7446-1ubuntu1_all.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/~scorpio/+archive/ubuntu/qelectrotech-dev/+files/qelectrotech-examples_0.90.r7446-1ubuntu1_all.deb
```

Now, remove the version installed from the official repositories, and install the .deb packages

```
sudo apt remove qelectrotech
sudo apt remove qelectrotech-data
sudo apt remove qelectrotech-examples
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Now install any missing dependencies

```
sudo apt install -f
```

Finally, hold the packages in `apt`, so that it does not update to the "new version" which is actually older.

```
sudo apt-mark hold qelectrotech qelectrotech-data qelectrotech-examples
```

Comment: All good, but APT-pinning is more reliable. See https://askubuntu.com/q/1002703/66509 .

Comment: I use synaptic package manager. And I can force correct version. But I need to lock version too as if I don't do that the next update will downgrade version. And I like to have unlocked version so they will be updated when new one is available.

Comment: @N0rbert I am not much familiar with APT-pinning. Please feel free to edit or add your own answer (whichever one you prefer).

Comment: @eSlavko please add the output `apt-cache policy qelectrotech` to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/1185620). This will allow us to create pinning file.