# how to disable permanently package ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: boot, 20.04, kernel

I have a problem if I upgrade / update the kernel then the operating system error because I have an old version of my laptop. so I want to permanently disable the package to update / upgrade the kernel how do I do it?

i use this command

```
sudo apt-mark hold linux-headers-5.13.0-30-generic
sudo apt-mark hold linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-30
sudo apt-mark hold linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic
sudo apt-mark hold linux-modules-5.13.0-30-generic
sudo apt-mark hold linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-30-generic
```

but after rebooting linux still asks for a kernel upgrade, I'm confused, how to permanently disable this kernel update / upgrade, I want to keep using the default kernel from ubuntu 20.04 which is kernel 5.8.0

Comment: Please clarify your OS & release, as you've tagged it's a 14.04 release and 20.04?  Ubuntu 20.04 supported kernels are GA = 5.4 & HWE = 5.13, plus some OEM options with the 5.8 kernel **not** being a *supported* 20.04 or *focal* kernel; so are you using Ubuntu?  (5.8 was the kernel at 20.04.2 if using HWE, but ceased being *supported* at 20.04.3 as it then used 5.11, at 20.04.4 it upgraded to 5.13; the GA kernel is the *stable* option that does **not** change during the life of the LTS release)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is more reliable - apt-mark or APT-pin (/etc/apt/preferences.d/pin) for version locking?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002703/what-is-more-reliable-apt-mark-or-apt-pin-etc-apt-preferences-d-pin-for-ver)